# Multiple user types - inheritence or composition?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, composition

I have two "types" of Accounts in my site, with VERY different functionality, and a few different fields between them. These two types, however, share the same table of "basic account" fields.

Is it better, in this case to utilize an inheritance design, where User and Company are simply children of Account, or is it better to use a composition design, where an Account can have either a "user" or a "company" (each with their own functionality) object in it?

Note: the Account table contains the primary id that connects all the types together, and therefore is the way I will actually derive each user or company.

**ALSO**

I get that this is a fairly subjective question, but I know that there are common practices out there. It makes sense that there should be ideas on when it's right to do one and right to do another - therefore a right and wrong answer.

Comment: .. or a "user" have an account object in it. it all depends on the usage patterns

Comment: There is no *correct* answer for this question.

Comment: So, is that to say that a composition method might be the best way, because it allows for flexibility? AKA - I can load a user object, and then it's account object, or vice versa? Whereas, with an inheritance model, (I think) I am forced to load the User object and extend it from Account?

Comment: Also, I don't understand the attempt to close this. It's a best practice question, where I need to know when the answer is one vs. the other. It's rare that there is any real ONE answer for any problem on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "User" and "Company" are kind of "Account" (like UserAccount and CompanyAccount), then use inheritance.

If, on the other hand, User and Company are distinct entities that happen to have an Account, then use composition.

Comment: It is the case that both Users and Companies log in with the same account information. Account is more or less a means of authentication, while User and Company are the "privileges" that we extend to that account.

Comment: You mean like IndividualAccount vs. CorporateAccount? It is always a person that logs in, yes?

Comment: Yes...a person logs in, but in one case they represent themselves, and in the other, they represent a company. "Users" on our site can only read things that "Companies" post. Depending on which type of account you have, your experience on the site changes drastically.

Comment: Just to be clear, the log in process for "User" and "Company" are 100% the same. A single email per account, etc.

Comment: If you care about different kinds of "Account", then inheritance seems like a better choice. Or you can have an Account class and Privileges class and both "User" and "Company" are just a different instances of Privileges...

Comment: Yeah...where it becomes strange is when I know the account id, but not whether or not the account is for a user or company. At that point the only way I can see to load either of the children classes is to first query the account table to see what type they are, and then load/query the user or company models themselves...am I missing something? (wouldn't doubt it, haha)

Comment: You need to define what "Account" is responsible for. Once you do that, you will find out what data it needs to perform.